# MySQL - Get total count of specific IDs

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
    MYTABLE    
|-------------|
| ID | COLOR  |
|----|--------|
| 01 | WHITE  |
| 01 | BLACK  |
| 01 | YELLOW |
| 02 | RED    |
| 02 | BLUE   |
| 02 | YELLOW |
| 03 | BLACK  |
| 03 | BLUE   |
| 03 | YELLOW |
|-------------|
```

When I want to get all colors from an ID, I execute this query:

```
SELECT `COLOR` FROM `MYTABLE` WHERE `ID` = 2

  RESULT  
|--------|
| COLOR  |
|--------|
| RED    |
| BLUE   |
| YELLOW |
|--------|
```

How can I also get how many times each color exist in table?
What query I have to execute to get the following results?

```
HOW CAN I GET THIS?
|----------------|
| COLOR  | COUNT |
|--------|-------|
| RED    |   1   |
| BLUE   |   2   |
| YELLOW |   3   |
|----------------|
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    COLOR,
    count(*) as `COUNT`
From 
    MYTABLE
GROUP BY COLOR;
```

You can add where condition with `Where ID = 2` before `group by` if there multiple colors available for each ID

Now if you need to find the total time each color appear in the table irrespective of the id and then filter data with ID then you can use the following

```
select 
t1.COLOR,
cnt as `count`
from MYTABLE t1
inner join (
  select 
  COLOR,
  count(*) as cnt
  from MYTABLE
  group by COLOR
)t2
on t2.COLOR = t1.COLOR
where t1.id = 2
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbfe82/6)**

Comment: The first query has count=1 on all rows. I need the total count.
The second query return this error: Can't reopen table: 't1'

Comment: not sure about the error you are getting its working for me http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbfe82/5

Comment: Sorry! I tested it using `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`. How stupid am I?
It is working excellent! THANKS!